# Console font not found?

Tags: arch-linux, fonts

I am getting an error when I update Arch linux which is "Console font not found". However, I looked in /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts and the font specified is indeed there. Do I need to put it somewhere else? The exact error sequence is as follows:

```
==> Starting build: 6.1.7-arch1-1
.....
  -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
  -> Running build hook: [keymap]
  -> Running build hook: [consolefont]
==> ERROR: consolefont: requested font not found: `sun12x22.psfu.gz'
```

Comment: That's a [`mkinitcpio` warning...](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/mkinitcpio/mkinitcpio/-/issues/139)  you can [ignore it